# Given $a, b$ coprime integers, show that any factor of $a^2 - 2b^2$ is of the form $c^2 - 2d^2$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

This is an exercise from Fermat's Last Theorem: A Genetic Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory.

I imagine the relevant ring here is $Z[\sqrt{2}]$, i.e., we can factor $a^2 - 2b^2$ into $(a + b\sqrt{2})(a - b\sqrt{2})$. This ring is also a Euclidean domain, hence a UFD also. I don't have too much experience, and I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any advice? I guess I want to show any integer factor of $a^2 - 2b^2$ can be written as $(c + d\sqrt{2})(c - d\sqrt{2})$ but I don't know how to get there with what I have.

Comment: Use definition and multiplicativity of norms in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$

Answer (score 1):

As written, this is false! For example $3\mid 3^2 -2(3^2)$. However, it is true if $a^2-2b^2$ is *squarefree*.

---

First, observe that if $m = a^2-2b^2$ and $n = c^2-2d^2$, then
$$mn= (ac-2bd)^2-2(ad-bc)^2$$
is also of that form. In particular, it is sufficient to show that every *prime* factor is of that form.

You're right that we want to work in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$.

It's easy to check that $2$ is of the required form. If $p$ is an odd prime, then we can rephrase the question as follows:

> If $p\mid a^2-2b^2$, then $p$ is the norm of some element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$.

For odd primes $p$, this is equivalent to asking for $p$ to split completely in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$. So rephrasing again, the question is:

> If $p$ is an odd prime and there exist $a,b$ with $a^2-2b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, then $p$ splits completely in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$.

Can you finish from here? You'll need to use the fact that $a^2-2b^2$ is squarefree.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand up to the point where you mention $p$ splitting completely. When looking up the terminology I came across some Galois theory which I haven't really delved into. A prime splitting means it is the product of at least two distinct elements of $Z[\sqrt{2}]$ ? It's not obvious to me how this is equivalent to the statement about the norm, could you explain this or provide a resource to learn more about prime splitting? Is it just because if p is of the given form, it factorizes into two distinct elements (specifically an element and its conjugate) of the ring?

Comment: Ah - in which case this answer may be too advanced. The connection comes from multiplicativity of norms and the fact that the norm of an ideal is related to the norm of it's generator. The norm of $p\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$ is $p^2$. If $p$ splits, then the norm of each of the ideals it splits into will be $p$.

Comment: Essentially, $p$ is a norm of an element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ if and only if $p$ is no longer prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$.